# Zend_Filter_Input replacement

Tags: magento2.4.6, laminas, zend

in a module that I have to maintain, the function Zend_Filter_Input is used, but in 2.4.6 it throws an error. Is there a replacement ? (I know for Zend_Json for example it's Laminas\Json\Json) but here I have no clue. Any help or pointers appreciated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can replace with **Magento\Framework\Filter\FilterInput**. Like:

```
$inputFilter = new \Magento\Framework\Filter\FilterInput(
        ['date_from' => $this->dateFilter, 'date_to' => $this->dateFilter],
        [],
        $data
    );
```

Also **laminas/laminas-filter** is already available with 2.4.6. You can use **Laminas\Filter;**
[Here is the detail](https://docs.laminas.dev/laminas-filter/intro/)